# reactのチュートリアルはなぜポート番号を指定？

Tags: reactjs

**ポート番号指定について**
reactチュートリアルのサーバサイドが分からないので教えてください。
・最終的に下記へアクセスして確認するみたいですが、なぜ`ポート番号を指定`しているのでしょうか？

> And visit http://localhost:3000/.

・server.phpを見るとポート処理が書いてあるのですが、これは何のため？
・ないとセキュリティ的にマズい？
・それとも開発確認用途で記述しているだけ(？)で、削除しても良い？
・アクセス先をhttp://localhost/hoge/みたいに変更するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

**手順**
・手順的には、下記3つのコマンドを打てば良いのでしょうか？
・expressは自動的に入る？
・npm install
・node server.js
・php server.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ポート番号を指定しているのは、開発用途で標準のポートと衝突しないようにするためです。セキュリティには関係無いです。
　http://localhost/hoge/のようにしたい場合は、apacheやnginxなどでリバースプロキシを設置したりする方法があります。説明は大変なので、詳細は調べてみてください。

server.phpはphpでサーバーを起動したい場合に使うもので、server.jsをphpで書き換えたものです。よって、`npm install`したあとは、`node server.js`か`php server.php`のいずれかのみで構いません。

Comment: ローカルで80番ポートを使っていないのであれば、 `PORT=80 node server.js` などとしても問題ないのでしょうか？

Comment: 問題ないと思います。但し私がUbuntuで試したところ、1023以下のポートを使う場合は、ユーザー権限ではアクセス拒否されたので、`sudo PORT=80 node server.js`とする必要がありました。